# Error creating file with blob (react): object must have a callable @@iterator property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer to take a file I've uploaded and resize it before I send it along a backend API that does some analysis.

Right now I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': The object must have a callable
> @@iterator property

My understanding is that the file constructor can take a blob as the first argument and that the resizer function is providing that blob. So, I'm not sure where I'm short circuiting. I do know my input is good as I have another resizer called in the same component that is working (it provides a base64 encoded version of the resized file that I display as the original image before processing)

The relevant code is:

```
uploadImageHandler = (event) => {
    const tempImage = event.target.files[0];
    const imageType = tempImage.type;

    Resizer.imageFileResizer(
      tempImage,
      300,
      300,
      imageType,
      100,
      0,
      (uri) => {
        const file = new File(uri, tempImage.name);
      },
      'blob',
    );
};
```

When I do a console.log on `uri` just before I try and do the `new File` it returns

```
Blob {size: 127332, type: "image/image/jpeg"}
size: 127332
type: "image/image/jpeg"
__proto__: Blob
arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
size: (...)
slice: ƒ slice()
stream: ƒ stream()
text: ƒ text()
type: (...)
constructor: ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
get size: ƒ size()
get type: ƒ type()
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 5):

> My understanding is that the file constructor can take a blob as the first argument and that the resizer function is providing that blob.

This is almost correct :). If we read the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) carefully:

> Syntax
>
> `new File(bits, name[, options]);`
>
> `bits`
>
> An **Array !!!** of `ArrayBuffer`, `ArrayBufferView`, `Blob`, ...

So I think if you change your code from:

```
...
(uri) => {
   const file = new File(uri, tempImage.name);
...
```

to:

```
...
(uri) => {
   const file = new File([uri], tempImage.name);
...
```

it should work without the problem you described.

This is just my guess - I did not test it!

Answer (score -2):

In version 0.4.2, you can give **"file"** property to **outputType**. For details: [read the documentation](https://github.com/onurzorluer/react-image-file-resizer#react-image-file-resizer)

Comment: How does this answer the question?